# In VLC player, how do I clear a playlist filled with many videos in one shot (instead of deleting one by one)?

Tags: vlc-media-player

When one has many clips in the playlist, how do i delete them all in one go? Curently, I press delete 22 times in a row to delete 22 videos! I rather use the same colour/brightness settings that's why I reuse instead of closing the player and opening up a new one.

Comment: Note that you can store these settings in the preferences.

Answer (score 4):

Clear playlist using the hotkey <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>W</kbd>

Comment: According to the VLC wiki that hotkey does NOT clear the playlist: https://wiki.videolan.org/hotkeys_table/ You may have a custom setting somewhere and this answer does not apply.

Comment: From the command line, type
[vlc --help]

and see for yourself

You are not launching a wiki, you are launching vlc.  Therefore, the local copy of vlc prevails, without regard to any wiki.

Comment: Please explain. When I run .\vlc.exe --help the help text that shows is help for the command line interaction and contains no information about CTRL- hotkeys. Further, the wiki I'm referring to is the official online helpfile by videolan: https://wiki.videolan.org/hotkeys_table/

Comment: I will explain AFTER you simply open VLC, load a playlist, then clear it with the hotkey ctrl+w.

And, my bad on the [vlc --help].  Use the more exhaustive [vlc -H]

Further, I do not recall where I learned the hotkey.  Been using since Day 1.

Comment: You are correct and I was not. I found one reference on a forum about a script that adds this capability to VLC, but none of the documentation available lists this key combination.

Answer (score 0):

You can select all the clips with your mouse, then hit the <kbd>DEL</kbd> button to delete the selected clips.

Answer (score 0):

If you're talking about VLC in a window, then with the playlist open, press <kbd>CTRL</kbd><kbd>A</kbd> to select all the elements in the playlist, then press <kbd>DEL</kbd> to delete all tracks ;)

Answer (score 0):

Other than with <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd>, you can also drag with your mouse around the files, and press <kbd>DEL</kbd>.

Dragging and dropping also works well, to add new files.

Answer (score 0):

Right-click in the playlist window and select Clear Playlist.

Answer (score 0):

The CTRL+w hotkey is listed in the GUI.  Preferences/All/Interface/Hotkeys Settings - scroll way way down the list.  It is there.

What a stiki wiki this is.

Comment: Hi Cerebrated Freak, this answer was provided previously by Pepin Jacob-Deaver.

Answer (score 0):

## !/bin/bash

VAR=$(xdotool search --name vlc)
xdotool windowactivate --sync $VAR key ctrl+w & sleep .1
vlc PATHTOPLAYLISTxspf

Find the VLC window (docked playlist). Send CTRL+w to clear playlist. Open new playlist.

One click.